# Qt does not work with Botan_v1.10.1 Libraries

Tags: qt, gcc, mingw, mingw32, botan

I've been trying to get Qt 4.7.3 to work with the newest Botan v1.10.1 libraries.

There is a Botan binary for Windows but it seems that the *.dll files are only for MS Visual Studio.
So I tried to compile Botan with mingw32 so that I can get Qt compatible *.dll and *.a files.

**Some Extra Info:**
-Windows 7 64bit.
-Tried to compile in 32bit mode.
-Qt is newest everything and works great, installed in 32bit mode.
-Botan is v1.10.1 for x86 Windows.

I opened the Qt command prompt and issued the following command.

```
configure.py --cc=gcc --cpu=x86
```

This command generated a Makefile.

Then I usued this command.

```
mingw32-make
```

This command generates the following error after a few minutes of running.

> C:\Botan-1.10.1\src\utils\time.cpp: In function 'tm
>   Botan::::do_gmtime(time_t)':
>       C:\Botan-1.10.1\src\utils\time.cpp:55: error: 'gmtime_s' was not declared in this scope
>       mingw32-make: *** [build\lib\time.obj] Error 1

I opened C:\Botan-1.10.1\src\utils\time.cpp and changed this

```
#if defined(BOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_GMTIME_S)
   gmtime_s(&tm, &time_val); // Windows
#elif defined(BOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_GMTIME_R)
   gmtime_r(&time_val, &tm); // Unix/SUSv2
#else
   std::tm* tm_p = std::gmtime(&time_val);
   if (tm_p == 0)
      throw Encoding_Error("time_t_to_tm could not convert");
   tm = *tm_p;
#endif
```

to this

```
/*#if defined(BOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_GMTIME_S)
   gmtime_s(&tm, &time_val); // Windows
#elif defined(BOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_GMTIME_R)
   gmtime_r(&time_val, &tm); // Unix/SUSv2
#else*/
   std::tm* tm_p = std::gmtime(&time_val);
   if (tm_p == 0)
      throw Encoding_Error("time_t_to_tm could not convert");
   tm = *tm_p;
//#endif
```

Then I ran mingw32-make again.  This time it compiled more and got stuck on this error.

> C:\Botan-1.10.1>mingw32-make process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -f
>   libbotan-1.10.a, ...) failed. make (e=2): The system cannot find the
>   file specified. mingw32-make: *** [libbotan-1.10.a] Error 2

I can't get beyond this error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract botan from the Qt Creator source tree and use qmake and your gcc to build it.

Alternatively, use MinGW-w64's gendef or the MinGW.org equivalent to generate a .def file from the DLL, and use dlltool to create an import library.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to the concepts you suggested. With respect to the second suggestion, I have some questions. (1) When you mean *.dll file are you referring to the *.dll that comes with the binary install of Botan for Windows?  (2) Is generating a *.def file from a *.dll something I can rely or depend on?

Comment: (1) yes I mean the prebuilt DLL. (2) in general yes, there are corner cases, but I'll doubt you'll hit these with an open source library like Botan.

Comment: Mingw-w64 gendef doesn't seem to want to compile on windows.